Why does all these adaptive methods in neural network training require a $g_t^2$ term?
All the adaptive learning methods, AdaGrad, AdaDelta, RMSprop, ADAM, and later variants all require $g_t^2$ which is the gradient multiplying itself in the elementwise fashion.
Why is this needed? I have never found a convincing argument on this.

It's my first time reading up on this, but the squared term contributes to an estimate of the second moment, i.e. the variance of the gradient. You might intuitively understand that you want to change your step size dynamically based on how certain you are about your current estimate.
